# Trying to add some custom text into Wordpress Post title via function.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to add a custom text in wordpress Post title dynamically which I'm trying to add via this code in function.php

Following code is not working

```html
add_filter('the_title', 'new_title', 10, 2);
function new_title($title, $id) {
    if('babysitters' == get_post_type($id)){
        $exclusive = get_field('exclusive');
        $newtitle = $title .', ' .$exclusive->y;

    }
    else{

        $newtitle = $title;
    }
    return $newtitle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `get_field` but it's not in the Wordpress "loop" so you need to pass the post id into the function so it knows what post to use.

Assuming get_field is returning an object into the `$exclusive` variable, you just need to change your function to the following:

```
add_filter('the_title', 'new_title', 10, 2);
function new_title($title, $id) {
    if('babysitters' == get_post_type($id)){
        $exclusive = get_field('exclusive', $id);   // pass the id into get_field
        $title = $title .', ' .$exclusive->y;
    }
    return $title;
}
```